# How To : Entity framework and multiple schemas

Tags: .net, entity-framework, multiple-schema

I am working with Entity framework. I am using a single database with multiple schemas as,
mySchema1.Employee
mySchema2.Employee
mySchema3.Employee

When I generate edmx for this database, it renames the tables as Employee1, Employee2, Employee3 etc.

How to achieve multiple schemas implementation with single edmx.

**Edit:**
The objects should be called by same name here as Employee. Only the variable part is schema.
ctx.Employee - should fetch data from a specific schema. I am looking for something where I can specify which to be used.

Please help.

Comment: What do you *want* it to call the objects it creates?

Comment: Do you want them all be called Employee? Can you state your intentions (what you would like to achieve) a little bit more?

Comment: @Styxxy - Please find edited part of question.

Comment: So you want to be able to specify whether to use `mySchema1.Employee` or `mySchema2.Employee` - do you mean you want to be able to choose at *run time*? Or when you are generating the edmx?

Comment: Either ways will do. Right now when I generate edmx it creates 3 different tables with different names.

Comment: did you solve this? I need the exact same thing! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether I understand the question... Do you want to have [multiple diagrams per model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj519700.aspx) ?

This feature is added in Entity Framework 5 which was recently released. Make sure you're using the latest version.