# Add new data with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I am trying to add new data to my database, here is my code:

```
// This is the dbContext
private BugTrackerDBContainer db = new BugTrackerDBContainer();

//The objet with its properties
public static Developper devAdded = new Developper();
devAdded.Name = txb_name.Text;
devAdded.FirstName = txb_firtname.Text;

// Add to the database
db.AddToDevelopper(devAdded);
db.SaveChanges();
```

My problem is that it I launch it once, it works fine, but twice I am having this error:

> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.

Why is it ?

Thanks for your helps

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Entity Framework "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128361/c-sharp-entity-framework-an-entity-object-cannot-be-referenced-by-multiple-inst)

Comment: 'devAdded' object should not be static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are all this mix of function and variables declaration?
You are trying to add the same static instance object twice to the same DataContext, it will fail.

- Don't declare static variables. Is is bad.
- Don't declare you Context as a field. Use it as a local variable with using blocks.
- Don't mix access to UI element like textboxes with manipulation of database. Create layer in your application.

An example :

```
public void AddDevelopperButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.AddDevelopper(txb_name.Text, txb_firtname.Text);
}

public Developper AddDevelopper(string name, string firstName)
{
    Developper devAdded = new Developper();
    devAdded.Name = name;
    devAdded.FirstName = firstName;

    using(BugTrackerDBContainer db = new BugTrackerDBContainer())
    {
        db.AddToDevelopper(devAdded);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return devAdded;
}
```

Comment: Edit your question and post your entire code. What properties Developper as? Does it have a reference to another property?

Comment: I miscopied the code, I tried it once again, works perfectly, cheers for your comments about the best practices, what to do and what not...thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have your database entity as a static object. The problem is most likely this line:

```
public static Developper devAdded = new Developper();
```

Change the code to what was recommended by @Scorpi0.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestions are:

A: Learn basic programming

What possible reason declare static:

```
public static Developper devAdded = new Developper();
```

B: Then start looking into EF and other frameworks later.